# Long db query result with concurrent write at the same time

Tags: sql, database, concurrency, database-performance, nosql

I'm curious. I have flow like that: We have big collection/table with a lot of data. And have some `select` oriented query which is long and takes 3 seconds.

However we looking to highly concurrent environment and each seconds we get 100 new records in our database.

So let's say we have a query, and before that query starts we have 1000 items which satisfy those query. Query takes 3 seconds, and each seconds there is 50 new items that match those query added to the db. My questions is - which is result this query return to me (is it still 1000 or 1150 or something in between) and how this depend from different database engine (SQL, NoSQL). O

It's not a question about exact number, but a bit more - why it will be those number.

---

Looks like question is a bit wide. Let's limit DB with MySQL, Postgres, MongoDB and Cassandra.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking generally (mainly because you didn't name a specific database), the concurrency level of a database is configurable, and falls under the category of performance tuning.

Some common lock granularities are:

- ROW - only a single row of data is locked at a time
- PAGE - some group of rows is locked at a time
- TABLE - the entire table is locked

So, if you used ROW level locking, you would likely get all 1150 results, at the expense of higher locking overhead.  Or, if you used TABLE level locking, you would get 1000 results very quickly, but at the expense of your data stream being blocked from writing to your db for 3s.

Comment: Thanks. So if it's table lock than all write request made during query will fail?

Comment: @ph0en1x not quite.  The write requests will block (because they are waiting to obtain a lock) and they may fail via timeout if they spend too much time waiting to obtain a lock.  But the timeout values are generally configurable as well.

Comment: Yes, I understand this. But question was a bit general.

Comment: Are you sure you would get all 1150 rows with row locking? Why? My guess is anywhere between 1000 and 1150.